# registering the BroadCastReceiver in code error IntentReceiverLeaked

Tags: java, android

I am trying to stop a service from my **BroadCastReceiver** when the charger is disconnected but when I run my code I get **IntentReceiverLeaked** in LogCat.
I am registering my receiver from a Service **MyAlarmServiceClass**.

```
public class MyAlarmServiceClass extends Service
{
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent)
    {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId)
    {
        listener=new StopListener();
        registerReceiver(listener,new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_POWER_DISCONNECTED));

        return START_STICKY;
    }    

    @Override
    public void onDestroy()
    {
         if(listener!=null)
        {
            this.unregisterReceiver(listener);
        }

        super.onDestroy();
    }
}
```

**Here is my BroadcastReceiver**

```
public class StopListener extends BroadcastReceiver
{
    SharedPreferences Stop_SharedPreferences;
    boolean stop;
    NotificationManager manager;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {

        Stop_SharedPreferences=context.getSharedPreferences("stopService", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        stop=  Stop_SharedPreferences.getBoolean("stopServices",true);

        if(stop)
        {
            context.stopService(new Intent(context, MyAlarmServiceClass.class));
        }
    }
}
```

**Here is the logcat report**

```
 android.app.IntentReceiverLeaked: Service www.androidghost.com.batteryalarm.MyAlarmServiceClass has leaked IntentReceiver www.androidghost.com.batteryalarm.StopListener@d029e6f that was originally registered here. Are you missing a call to unregisterReceiver()?
            at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher.<init>(LoadedApk.java:1167)
            at android.app.LoadedApk.getReceiverDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:950)
            at android.app.ContextImpl.registerReceiverInternal(ContextImpl.java:1339)
            at android.app.ContextImpl.registerReceiver(ContextImpl.java:1319)
            at android.app.ContextImpl.registerReceiver(ContextImpl.java:1313)
            at android.content.ContextWrapper.registerReceiver(ContextWrapper.java:596)
            at www.androidghost.com.batteryalarm.MyAlarmServiceClass.onStartCommand(MyAlarmServiceClass.java:64)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:3375)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap21(ActivityThread.java)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1621)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:163)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6221)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:904)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:794)
```

Comment: You need to unregister the receiver in `onDestroy()`

Comment: In which class?

Comment: In your service class. That is `MyAlarmServiceClass` in your snippet

Comment: I have done this but it again give same error

Comment: Post full `MyAlarmServiceClass` class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `onStartCommand` was called multiple times (and your receiver was registered multiple times). Try to register your receiver in `onCreate` of your service